# Skewed Text is getting blurred in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a skewed popup and text in the quick view of products. But its not rendering correctly in chrome. I tried translate 3d(0,0,0) and also changes the skew deg from odd to even but it doesn't resolved my problem.
Anyone can please help me with this.

Comment: It is also not perfect in firefox. It keeps relocating

Comment: I've tried fiddling around with :before and :after borders, I couldnt get the desired solution unfortionally

Answer (score 0):

Blurring is minor issue while skewing for making the items look smoother. If you really need to make the blurring gone, simply skew only the background div and leave the foreground div untouched.

```css
.background {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
}
.foreground {
  width: 280px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.dialog {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="foreground">
    <p>Here goes some foreground text.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the necessary vendor-prefixes for other browser than webkit-based, please? I use Firefox and feel left out.

Comment: @klaar with vedor-prefixes: -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);-moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);-ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);-o-transform: skewY(-5deg);transform: skewY(-5deg);